# DevExpress ComboBoxEdit datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using DevExpress ComboBoxEdit and I need to bind list to its datasource. But as I can see there is no method to add datasource to control, so I added each item to control one by one like

```
foreach (var item in list) {
    comboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.Add(item);
}
```

It worked for but it is slow if there is lot of data.
Is there a way where I can bind list directly to control?

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to bind the ComboBoxEdit directly to the datasource because the ComboBoxEdit is designed to be used when you need a simple predefined set of values. Use the [LookUpEdit](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic) when you need to use a datasource.
You can use the the [ComboBoxItemCollection.BeginUpdate](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsComboBoxItemCollection_BeginUpdatetopic) and [ComboBoxItemCollection.EndUpdate](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsComboBoxItemCollection_EndUpdatetopic) methods to prevent excessive updates while changing the item collection:

```
ComboBoxItemCollection itemsCollection = comboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items;
itemsCollection.BeginUpdate();
try {
    foreach (var item in list) 
        itemsCollection.Add(item);
}
finally {
    itemsCollection.EndUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach to add items en-mass to a combobox using a linq one-liner:

```
  comboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.AddRange(newItems.Select(x => x.SomeStringPropertyHere as object).ToArray());
```

The .AddRange() method takes care to invoke BeginUpdate()/EndUpdate() internally.

Comment: Nice, I went with:   MyCollection.ForEach(i => this.comboBox.Properties.Items.Add(i));

Comment: I am afraid that calling the .Add() method on each every item will cause BeginUpdate()/EndUpdate() to be called N times (where N is the number of items in the collection) instead of just once as when using AddRange(). Spamming BeginUpdate()/EndUpdate() * N have a negative impact on performance for "large" collections due to said repeated calls. Just my 2c.

Answer (score 0):

And another approach is through an extension method:

```
    public static ComboBoxEdit AddItemsToCombo(this ComboBoxEdit combo, IEnumerable<object> items)
    {
        items.ForEach(i => combo.Properties.Items.Add(i));
        return combo;
    }
```